# Magento 2 static content folder sync

Tags: magento2, aws, cdn, cloudfront-cdn

I have multiple EC2 servers running magento 2.2.5 application. I am using Cloudfront CDN for pub/media serving and the source is s3 bucket.Also I have a cron at every 1 minute that sync pub/media to s3 bucket.

Now I want to do same with my pub/static folder I created the similar 1 min cron but the issue is static folder has _cache folder that creates the js and css cache dynamically and when user opens the website and the cron yet haven't upload the file to s3 the user sees broken page of website.

Any solution for this for syncing it to bucket properly or any additional plugin / customisation might work?

Comment: have you found any solution for this. I am looking for same.